# Fabric does not close the ssh connection

Tags: python, ssh, fabric, paramiko

I'm using fabric and trying to execute some commands on a remote machine.
I have written a python client which does this job.

```
@task
@serial
def execute_command(timeout, command):
    if timeout == -1:
        return run(command, shell=False, pty=False, warn_only=True)
    else:
        return run(command, shell=False, pty=False, warn_only=True, timeout=int(timeout))
```

It does schedule the job, but the problem is that whenever there is a job that takes more than 30 seconds or so, it never comes out of execute_command. And timeout does not work too.

When I do `ss -t | less` and check the socket activity, the ssh connection pertaining to that command is still active. And it remains active till I kill it. It never dies by itself.

Can you anybody help me out with this? I want it to come out and also for the timeout to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

When I disabled the psuedo terminal option in the arguments for run, I was able to achieve what I wanted.